# JIRA Plugins SDK: How to find out changed data?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using the JIRA plugins sdk to work on changed Issues.

I´ve implemented an IssueListener and I have access to the Issue itself and the IssueEvent.

**How do I find out which property (summary, description, estimation ...) of my Issue has been changed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changelog is likely to contain what's been changed and there is a method on the IssueEvent object to get this (`getChangeLog`) and it returns a [GenericValue](http://oss.org.cn/ossdocs/applications/ofbiz/ofbiz-2.1.1-docs/website/core/docs/api/org/ofbiz/core/entity/GenericValue.html) object.

[This post](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/223177/issue-updated-event-contents) on the Atlassian Answers site gives some code related to an Atlassian tutorial on [how to write JIRA Event Listeners](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library).

The relevant code snippet is shown below:

```
if (eventTypeId.equals(EventType.ISSUE_UPDATED_ID)) {
    List<GenericValue> changeItems = null;

    try {
        GenericValue changeLog = issueEvent.getChangeLog();
        changeItems = changeLog.internalDelegator.findByAnd("ChangeItem", EasyMap.build("group",changeLog.get("id")));
    } catch (GenericEntityException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    log.info("number of changes: {}",changeItems.size());
    for (Iterator<GenericValue> iterator = changeItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
        GenericValue changetemp = (GenericValue) iterator.next();
            String field = changetemp.getString("field");
            String oldstring = changetemp.getString("oldstring");
            String newstring = changetemp.getString("newstring");
            StringBuilder fullstring = new StringBuilder();
            fullstring.append("Issue ");
            fullstring.append(issue.getKey());
            fullstring.append(" field ");
            fullstring.append(field);
            fullstring.append(" has been updated from ");
            fullstring.append(oldstring);
            fullstring.append(" to ");
            fullstring.append(newstring);
            log.info("changes {}", fullstring.toString());

            /* Do something here if a particular field you are
               looking for has being changed.
            */
            if(field == "Component") changeAssignee(changetemp, issue, user);
    }
}
```